# Go channels publish, receive and go routine scheduling

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

I have following piece of go script and I have questions regarding the channels reading data and the execution order of go routine.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func squares(c chan int) {
    fmt.Println("started squares goroutine...")
    for num := range c {
        //num := <-c
        fmt.Println(num * num)
    }
    fmt.Println("exiting squares goroutine...")
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("main() started")
    c := make(chan int, 3)

    go squares(c)

    c <- 1
    printChannel(c)
    c <- 2
    printChannel(c)
    c <- 3
    printChannel(c)
    c <- 4
    fmt.Println("after publish 4")
    printChannel(c)
    c <- 5
    fmt.Println("after publish 5")
    printChannel(c)
    c <- 6
    printChannel(c)
    c <- 7
    printChannel(c)
    c <- 8
    printChannel(c)

    fmt.Println("main() stopped")
}

func printChannel(c chan int) {
    fmt.Println("length: ",len(c))
    fmt.Println("capacity: ",cap(c))
    
}
```

Output:

```
main() started
length:  1
capacity:  3
length:  2
capacity:  3
length:  3
capacity:  3
started squares goroutine...
1
4
9
16
after publish 4
length:  0
capacity:  3
after publish 5
length:  0
capacity:  3
length:  1
capacity:  3
length:  2
capacity:  3
length:  3
capacity:  3
main() stopped
```

Questions:

1. The capacity of the channel ch created is 3, but until 4 is published to the channel the channel is not read in the squares go routine, if the capacity is 3 where is 4 stored int the channel
2. After all the numbers are read from the channel, again number 5 is published to the channel, but the length of the channel is still 0, why?

Goplayground link for the code: https://play.golang.org/p/TmCcZt5n58f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no guarantee in the order of execution of goroutines, nor is there a guarantee of when a goroutine is interrupted (I/O, including printing to stdout, will be the most common cause for rescheduling).

For your first question: you can see that `16` is being printed before `after publish 4`. This means that the `squares` goroutine read from the channel and printed the square before the main goroutine could start printing information. By the time the main goroutine tries to print the length of the channel, `4` is already gone from it.

Similarly, after sending `5` to the channel, the `squares` goroutine has received it, but has not yet printed it. It got interrupted before the print. This means that the channel is empty again, but we haven't seen `25` yet.

If you run your example a number of times, you'll see different outputs. Sometimes the `squares` goroutine gets all the way up to `64`, sometimes it doesn't. This is perfectly normal. In normal code, you would need to make sure you wait for data to be consumed before exiting, and you wouldn't rely on the execution order or timing of different goroutines.